# Pointwise convergence of a sequence of real polynomials implies uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of real polynomials of deg $\le 5$. Suppose $P_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$ for $x$ in $[0,1]$. Prove $P_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

It would be easy if all the coefficients of the polynomials are of the same signs. But how to solve the problem if the signs of coefficients are mixed?

Comment: Presumably you mean uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to math.se What have you tried so far? You might consider checking [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/dealing-with-zero-effort-questions) to get used to the norms here. Also try learning $\LaTeX$. A simple tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3):

Choose 6 distinct points $x_k \in [0,1]$ and form the matrix
$V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & \cdots & x_1^5 \\
1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_2^5 \\ \vdots & & & \vdots \\
1 & x_6 & \cdots & x_6^5 \end{bmatrix} $, and note that the Vandermonde matrix $V$ is invertible.

If $\pi(x) = p_1+p_2x + \cdots + p_6 x^5$, then
$V p = \begin{bmatrix} \pi(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ \pi(x_6)\end{bmatrix}$, or in other words,
$p =V^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \pi(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ \pi(x_6)\end{bmatrix}$.

Consequently, if we let $r_n = V^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} P_n(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ P_n(x_6)\end{bmatrix}$, we see that $r_n \to 0$, and since
$|P_n(x)| \le  6\|r_n\|_\infty$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, we have the desired result.

Aside: Note that $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^6 [r_n]_k x^{k-1}$, so $|P_n(x)| \le  \sum_{k=1}^6 |[r_n]_k| $ since $|x| \le 1$ and so $|P_n(x)| \le 6 \|r_n\|_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain more why |Pn(x)|≤∥rn∥∞ for all x in [0,1]?

Comment: There was a missing constant which I have fixed. I added a note that hopefully explains the bound. (Note it would have been better to use $\|r_n\|_1$ instead, but they are all equivalent so I just left it alone.)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot:)!